# setting KOMA heading within lua

Tags: luatex, koma-script

I can `tex.print()` to set the `\title` command of my document, but when I try `tex.print('\\rohead{...})`, nothing appears.. any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
tex.print('\\title{TITLE}')
tex.print('\\rohead{R-HEAD}') -- why is this not setting?
tex.print('\\global\\rohead{R-HEAD}') -- why is this not setting?
\end{luacode*}
\lohead{L-HEAD}
% \rohead{THIS WORKS}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\clearpage
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't caused by `tex.print` but by the surrounding `luacode` environment. If you use `\luaexec` (or even just `\directlua`) instead then you can set this. Your attempt to add `\global` didn't work since `\global` only really works with TeX primitive setting commands, not with LaTeX commands.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{luacode}
\luaexec{
tex.print('\\title{TITLE}')
tex.print('\\rohead{R-HEAD}')
}
\lohead{L-HEAD}
% \rohead{THIS WORKS}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\clearpage
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain why this a shortcoming of `luacode`?

Comment: @likethevegetable `luacode` adds a group around the whole thing. Therefore all local settings (including `\rohead`) are only active until the end of the group which occurs at `\end{luacode*}`. `luaexec` on the other hand also executes in a group, but the code written using `tex.write` and friends is moved out of this group and therefore can have a longer effect. `\directlua` avoids groups completely.

Comment: Thank you. Let's say that the `\luaexec{}` call occurred inside of the group. Is there any way to "free" it? Are you able to answer why the KOMA command is affected but not the (I assume more generic) `\title`?

Comment: @likethevegetable If you don't want the group, use `\directlua`. `\luaexec` by design changes the meaning of e.g. `\\`, so in order to undo this at the end it is restricted to a group. `\title` is not affected since it is always global. That's mostly because you only want one title in your document, while you might want to change `\rohead` only for parts of a document and therefore want to restrict it to a group.

Comment: That's understandable. Although, since `\rohead` is performed in the pre-amble, it's unfortunate (for me) that it did not work as expected. For what it's worth, in my actual usage I made an environment to parse data and set document parameters. In my actual use, it was my environment that was causing the mishap and it was by chance that my MWE for SE used `luacode` and (luckily!) the mishap persisted.. I found that using `etoolbox`'s `\AfterEndEnvironment{myenv}{\luaexec{...}}` worked.